# Building a framework 7 + react template in cordova

Tags: cordova, webpack, html-framework-7

i downloaded this template of framework7 + react code:

https://github.com/framework7io/framework7-template-react

It works and build good in dev/prod, works fine in the browser.

Then i want to insert the result of the build in a cordova app.

So installed cordova, i do

```
$ cordova create myapp

$ cordova platform add android
```

i move all the content of the build process ( an index.html and relative static folder that contains css and js and images ) in the www folder of the cordova app.

I do a cordova build

The app is white, a blank html.

So then i figured out that i need to remove the trailing slash from my built files:
the link to JS and images have to change from '/static/file.js' to 'static/file.js' and then it start working.

Now i believe this can be configured in some way in the framework7 template, or with webpack, but the template use the react-scripts packages and i have no idea how to modify them.